# MySQL query for check if data exist and inserts or updates accordingly

Tags: mysql, sql

Following is mysql table

Table

1. Id (Incremental)
2. Date
3. Val-a
4. Val-b

I am looking for MySql query that checks if specific Date exist in the table

If date exist than update Val-a, Val-b with a new data

if NOT exist than add a new row of Date, Val-a, Val-b

Comment: May be this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723073/how-to-use-if-then-else-in-a-mysql-update-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `insert . . . on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into t(date, vala, valb)
    values (@date, @vala, @valb)
    on duplicate key update vala = values(vala), valb = values(valb);
```

For this to work, `date` needs to be a primary or unique key.